# jdbc 4.0 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, mysql

I'm developing an application using `Java and MySQL`. I've installed `libmysql-java` package as a database connector, but the installed connector implements version 3.0 of the JDBC specification.

Does anybody know which packages or connectors are needed to install for using `JDBC 4.0` in Ubuntu 12.04 using MySQL.

I'm using

- Java  (java version "1.7.0_04")
- MySQL (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-versions.html#.T8fUF2Yya15) `5.1.x` versions of `Connector/J` supports `JDBC 4.0` and the version of Connector/J available in latest Ubuntu repository is `libmysql-java 5.1.16-2`. So the driver you are using probably supports `JDBC 4.0`.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused because package description which does not suggest anything about jdbc 4.0

Comment: @Sky don't immediately go by package description.

Comment: Glad if it has helped, please accept it as the correct answer unless you need other information.

Answer (score 1):

One can download the latest connector from the [MySQL website](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Extract the tar and use mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar as `mysql-connector`